# connecting mysqld-exporter in docker - mysql_up 0

Tags: mysql, docker

What did I do:

```
1. docker run --net minha-rede --name mysql01 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Password1234 -d mysql

2. docker run --net minha-rede --name wordpress01 --link mysql01 -p 8080:80 -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql01:3306 -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=Password1234 -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress -e WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=wp_ -d wordpress

3. docker exec -it mysql01 bash

4. mysql -u root -p

5. CREATE USER 'luckerman'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'onboard' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 3;

6. GRANT PROCESS, REPLICATION CLIENT, SELECT ON *.* TO 'luckerman'@'localhost';

7. exit

8. exit

9. docker run -d \
  -p 9104:9104 --name mysqlexp01\
  --network minha-rede  \
  -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME="luckerman:onboard@(minha-rede:3306)/" \
  prom/mysqld-exporter
```

But when I run the `http://localhost:9104/metrics` I have the message `# TYPE mysql_exporter_last_scrape_error gauge
mysql_exporter_last_scrape_error 1`
and when I run `docker logs mysqlexp01` it shows me this:

> time="2018-09-11T20:57:40Z" level=info msg="Starting mysqld_exporter (version=0.11.0, branch=HEAD, revision=5d7179615695a61ecc3b5bf90a2a7c76a9592cdd)" source="mysqld_exporter.go:206"
>
> time="2018-09-11T20:57:40Z" level=info msg="Build context (go=go1.10.3, user=root@3d3ff666b0e4, date=20180629-15:00:35)" source="mysqld_exporter.go:207"
>
> time="2018-09-11T20:57:40Z" level=info msg="Enabled scrapers:" source="mysqld_exporter.go:218"
>
> time="2018-09-11T20:57:40Z" level=info msg=" --collect.info_schema.tables" source="mysqld_exporter.go:222"
>
> time="2018-09-11T20:57:40Z" level=info msg=" --collect.global_status" source="mysqld_exporter.go:222"
>
> time="2018-09-11T20:57:40Z" level=info msg=" --collect.global_variables" source="mysqld_exporter.go:222"
>
> time="2018-09-11T20:57:40Z" level=info msg=" --collect.slave_status" source="mysqld_exporter.go:222"
>
> time="2018-09-11T20:57:40Z" level=info msg="Listening on :9104" source="mysqld_exporter.go:232"
>
> time="2018-09-11T20:57:44Z" level=error msg="Error pinging mysqld: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused" source="exporter.go:119"

What I did wrong? I tried many forums, sites, etc...

Comment: You run mysql server in one container and mysql exporter in another one. You have to connect to `mysql01`, not `minha-rede`...

Comment: docker run -d \
  -p 9104:9104 --name mysqlexp01\
  --network minha-rede  \
  -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME="luckerman:onboard@(mysql01:3306)/" \
  prom/mysqld-exporter; this is the new error: Error pinging mysqld: Error 1045: Access denied for user 'luckerman'@'172.23.0.4' (using password: YES)" source="exporter.go:119

Comment: You should learn mysql basics and means to read and debug mysql errors. `CREATE USER 'luckerman'@'*'...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked! I did this:

docker network inspect minha-rede

Then I found the ip of my-sql (in my case 172.23.0.2)
Then I entered in my-sql and I did these commands:
CREATE USER 'luckerman'@'172.23.0.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'onboard' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 3;

GRANT PROCESS, REPLICATION CLIENT, SELECT ON *.* TO 'luckerman'@'172.23.0.2';

Thank you @alex-karshin!